# Change theme font in Word for Mac 2011?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, themes

Is it possible to change the theme fonts in Word for Mac 2011? By theme fonts, I mean when you click the font drop down menu, it suggests a 'Theme Heading' and 'Theme Body' font before the main list.

I found you can change them to some preselected options by opening PowerPoint, changing the theme there, saving the theme, and going back to Word. However, you can't select other fonts that aren't in the limited preselected options.

I also found how to change the font for individual styles, but this has no effect on the theme fonts.

I also tried unzipping the .thmx file, manually changing all of the references to the old theme font to my desired theme font, then rezipping and converting back to thmx. This corrupted the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took some effort. It's a bit tortuous, but it works (at least under Mavericks):

1. Open PowerPoint (sic) — new empty document.
2. Themes tab > Theme Options > Fonts.
   Look at the fonts in the different themes and decide which you will alter. I chose Office Classic (Arial, Times New Roman). Quit PowerPoint
3. Go to Applications > Microsoft Office 2011 >  Office > Media > Office Themes > Theme Fonts.
   Copy Office Classic.xml (or whatever) to a convenient place where you will edit it.
4. Open Classic Office.xml in a plain text editor (e.g. BBEdit). To change the Theme Heading font from Arial to Helvetica Neue I edited:
   `<a:latin typeface="Arial"/>` below `<a:majorFont/>`. Obviously you can do likewise for the minorFont.
5. Make a backup of the original Classic Office.xml file if you wish, and then replace it by your edited version.
6. Launch PowerPoint again. Select the Office Classic theme, which should now reflect your edits. In Theme Options > Save Theme, save to the desktop under a suitable name, e.g. new.thmx.  Quit PowerPoint.
7. Transfer new.thmx to Applications > Microsoft Office 2011 >  Office > Media > Office Themes.
8. Open Word. You should be able to choose your new theme from Themes under the Home tab. Now save the empty Word document (after making any other adjustments you require) as Normal.dotm. I'll assume you've saved in the default location, My Templates (the path to which is listed next).
9. Quit Word and go to 'your user name' > Library. (You may have to make Library visible by ticking the box in the View menu first.) The path to your file is

   > Library > Application Support > Microsoft > User Templates > My Templates
10. Transfer your new Normal.dotm to 'User Templates' after renaming the original one as a backup if you wish. (Make sure you spell Normal.dotm correctly.)
11. Open Word. Your default document now has your personalized fonts for Theme Headings and Theme body.

**Brief Update for Office 2016**

This sort of procedure is also possible for Office 2016. I managed to use the previous new.thmx I had created for 2011, but was able to save the new theme in 2016 without going the .dotm route. However, starting from scratch with Office 2016 requires a [different procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/1010672/change-theme-font-in-microsoft-word-mac-15/1326695#1326695) which I have posted in reply to another question.