# Change Theme Font in Microsoft Word (Mac) 15

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

How does one change the Font associated with the Theme?  I would rather not use Calibri.

[image: Word Theme Fonts on Font Menu]

Comment: If you mean "change the theme fonts for the current document," then I believe you go to the Design menu and select a new set of fonts from the Fonts dropdown (about 2/3 of the way along the ribbon). You can save the current theme+modifications by clicking "Set as default". If you mean "modify the theme so that when you select that theme, it has the fonts you want", sorry, I do not know.

Comment: @bibadia, thanks for the pointer. Please submit as an answer, rather than as a comment. I tried the Fonts menu, selecting Arial & Times. Strangely, it made Times the headline font, Arial the body font in the menu, but it made the entire document Arial, with no way to make it Times...

Comment: I've made some additional comments about the fonts and how you might be able to swap them around in an edit to my Answer. Unfortunately, AFAICS some VBA is needed to do it. I've checked that it works in a simple case with Word 2011 but not in Mac Word 2016 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the theme fonts for the current document, go to the Design menu and select a new set of fonts from the Fonts dropdown (about 2/3 of the way along the ribbon).

You can save the *current* theme + any such modifications by clicking "Set as default". However, that does not change the theme itself - if you create another document and select the same theme, the theme properties are the "factory default" ones (i.e. the ones defined by Microsoft).

As for the comment that the headline/body fonts are "the wrong way around,"
Yes, the available choices in the fonts dropdown seem very limited

- ISTR that it has been noticed that the Mac Word choice, i.e. Times
  for headers and Arial for body text, is the opposite of the Windows
  Word choice. But I'd have to check that to be sure.
- I cannot see any simple way within the Mac Word User Interface
  (again, not sure about the Windows side) to make your own choices.
  Word's Object Model does not seem to have any direct way to deal with
  this either. The expectation from Word 2007 onwards seems to be that
  you work with various XML files to achieve what you need, but as
  usual, the available documentation does not seem particularly
  informative as to how you modify the factory-supplied styles.
- However, with VBA, even on the Mac side, in Word 2011 it is possible
  to *export* the "ThemeFontScheme" for the current theme for a
  document. That creates a .xml file that you can edit (e.g. swap Arial
  and Times around) and then re-import.

For example, to export the ThemeFontScheme from the Active Document to a file, you can use VBA like this:

```
Sub exportThemeFontScheme()
Dim dt As Office.OfficeTheme
Set dt = ActiveDocument.DocumentTheme
' Substitute your username for "username"
dt.ThemeFontScheme.Save "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:myfontscheme.xml"
Set dt = Nothing
End Sub
```

You should then be able to edit that XML (e.g. in Mac OS X TextEdit) to define the fonts you need. I won't attempt the details right now but will try to edit this Answer when I have had a better look.

Save the resulting file. Then, you can re-import the FontScheme into the current document, using, e.g.

```
Sub importThemeFontScheme()
Dim dt As Office.OfficeTheme
Set dt = ActiveDocument.DocumentTheme
' Substitute your username for "username"
dt.ThemeFontScheme.Load "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:myfontscheme.xml"
Set dt = Nothing
End Sub
```

As you can tell, this is not a familiar area for me either!

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of the details. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have described an alternative way of doing this for Word 2011 [in another post](https://superuser.com/questions/983536/change-theme-font-in-word-for-mac-2011/1002987#1002987), and I have successfully applied the file that I generated for 2011 to Word 2016 (Word 15).

However for a clean version of Word 2016 the theme font xml files do not appear to be available. The procedure I have got to work is as follows. My objective was to set default fonts of Century Gothic (Headings) and Palatino Linotype (Body) to replace my already personalized Helvetica/Times combination.

1. Open PowerPoint (sic) — new empty document.
2. Go to the Design tab. From the first block of theme icons chose a graphic theme that suits you while you are about it, although this is irrelevant to the font.
3. ‘Save Current Theme’ (below theme icons in pull-down) under a suitable name, e.g. ‘CenturyPal’. This will save *CenturyPal.thmx* to:

> ~Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Themes

4. Quit PowerPoint without saving your document. Find *CenturyPal.thmx* in your file space, copy it somewhere suitable, and open it with an advanced text editor like BBEdit. You want to edit *theme1.xml* — see graphic below.

[image: edit major font]

6. Find `<a:majorFont><a:latin typeface=`and change the following text to ‘Century Gothic’ (or your desired major font) from whatever it is currently. (Mine was Helvetica Neue because that was my default. Yours would probably be Cambria.)
7. Find `<a:minorFont><a:latin typeface=`and change the font to ‘Palatino Linotype’ (or your desired minor font) from whatever it is currently. (Mine is Times New Roman. Yours may be Calibri.)

[image: edit minor font]

8. Save and return the edited *CenturyPal.thmx* file to the themes folder in ~Library…
9. Open Word, select the Design tab, then the ‘Themes’ icon on the extreme left.
10. Chose *CenturyPal*.

[image: Word Design Theme layout]

11. Click the tick box, ‘Set as Default’, and click ‘Yes’ on the dialogue box to confirm that you wish to change the defaults.
12. Go back to the Home tab. Check your fonts. The defaults are now Century Gothic and Palatino (or whatever you chose).
13. Quit and restart Word. The new defaults should have stuck.

**Addendum re High Sierra**

When I recently upgraded to High Sierra, Office upgraded itself and lost my custom font setting. Repeating the above restored them successfully.